# Why is my foreach printing out 2 char?

Tags: c#, foreach, output

I am trying to create an encryption (ceasar) for education and for some reason I can't seem to understand why my simple code (so far) is making such a hazzle

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string word;
        int key = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Write your messages");
        word = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your key cypher");
        key =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        encrypt(word, key);
    }

    static void encrypt(string message, int key)
    {
        foreach (char otherword in message)
        {
            Console.Write(otherword);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

If I write for example **test** after "Write your messages" and then place it into my `string word` and the use it in my function `encrypt`, it should output

```
t 
e
s
t
```

but for whatever god forsaken reason I get output like this

```
t
es
t
```

and I dont understand why.

Comment: Try using Console.WriteLine

Comment: Still getting the same problem

Comment: What keys do you press??

Comment: My words "test" and then enter-key

Comment: This would have been a good opportunity to use the debugger to see why your program was behaving in a way you didn't expect. You'll grow more as a developer that way. MSDN has some good information, if you're unfamiliar with debugging in Visual Studio. [Debugger Basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx) and [Debugging Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awtaffxb.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use `Console.WriteLine(otherword);` then. The spacing of the newlines in the output is dependent on which key you press after the `Console.Read();` line. (For example, if you press `[Enter]`, then you will get a newline, but if you press `A` you will not.)

You should probably also use `Console.ReadKey(true);` rather than `Console.Read();` as a method of separating your output, as this will make it so that the key you press does not show up.

Comment: Still getting the same problem.. and now I get a new line between the first T and ES

Comment: I think you meant to use `Console.ReadKey(true)`

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens Yes, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `Console.Read()` to `Console.ReadLine()` in your `encrypt` function. `Console.Read()` only reads the next character from the input stream. And since pressing the enter key generates two characters: `\r\n`, it is looping twice.

Comment: But how can I end my text without pressing enter?

Comment: changing it to ReadLine() will read both characters without having to iterate again, so you will still be able to press enter.

Comment: But I have `word = Console.ReadLine();`  ... and it still creates this new line

Comment: Yeah, and that's fine. But in your encrypt() function you are using Console.Read(). That's what needs to change.

Comment: When I did that I got a extra line between every char. like this **t** \n **e** \n **s** \n **t** \n

Answer (score 1):

In the encrypt method - change the Console.Write to Console.WriteLine and move the Console.Read() outside of the foreach.

```
    static void encrypt(string message, int key)
    {
        foreach (char otherword in message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(otherword);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.Read()` - or (even better) eliminate the line read entirely and use `Console.WriteLine(otherword)`.  `Read()` will mess with how the next line is formatted.